# Replace ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor in integration tests

Tags: spring, groovy, spring-scheduled

So, I've got a spring application that uses the @Scheduled annotation to do various jobs.  In prod, it works great.  However this feature causes us some problems when running spock integration tests-as soon as the container starts up, all our tasks are fired and it mucks up our test runs.

I'm looking for a way to turn off the scheduling functionality, but still have the container (configured with @ComponentScan) pick it up as a regular 'ol bean.

Based on some legwork I've done so far, it seems that if I could override the built-in ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor with a no-op implementation I could achieve this goal..but when I create this bean in the container(created using the @Bean("scheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"-see the code section below), it just seems to be added to the list of BeanPostProcessors-which still contains the original implementation.

```
   @Bean(name="scheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor")
    ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor  scheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor(){
        return new ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor(){
            @Override
            public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(final Object bean, String beanName){
                return bean
            }
        }


    }
```

So, I guess my question is-how can I wire in a bean that will replace a built-in BeanPostProcessor?  FYI I'm using Spring 3.2.4 and the application is configured 100% via Spring annotations.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My mistake was that I didn't name the bean correctly.  I ended up finding where this bean was being built(in org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.SchedulingConfiguration) and I copied it's configuration.

This method demonstrates the proper names/config:

```
@Bean(name=AnnotationConfigUtils.SCHEDULED_ANNOTATION_PROCESSOR_BEAN_NAME)
@Role(BeanDefinition.ROLE_INFRASTRUCTURE)
BeanPostProcessor scheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor(){
    return new  BeanPostProcessor(){
        @Override
        Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
            return bean
        }

        @Override
        Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
            return bean
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I needed to use `@Bean(name = TaskManagementConfigUtils.SCHEDULED_ANNOTATION_PROCESSOR_BEAN_NAME)` instead, but this works. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using a different version of Spring?

Comment: I should have noticed that you posted the version you were using. For future reference to help those who come upon this down the line, I'm using Spring 4.1.7.RELEASE via SpringBoot 1.2.5.RELEASE.