# Java SpringBoot method still @Scheduled under wrong @Profile?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

My `application.properties` file defines the default profile as `spring.profiles.active=test` and I have a method that I schedule like so:

```
  @Scheduled(initialDelay = 2500, fixedRate = 60 * 1000 * minutesRecheckRate)
  @Profile("loop")
  public void processingLoop() {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(env.getActiveProfiles()));
    //.. the rest is omitted for brevity.
```

To my understanding, under these circumstances I should never see this get called while running my unit-tests because I do not change the default profile. This turns out not to be the case, as this is still getting scheduled and I see the output

```
[test]
```

in my console despite my best efforts to prevent it. What is happening? Why is this still running even with a different active profile?

UPDATE:
I can't give much more due to the fact this is a work-relevant application, but I'll give what I can.

The class is configured like so:

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class BatchConfiguration {
```

The unit tests are all annotated like this:

```
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = SpringBatchJsontestApplication.class)
public class SpringBatchJsontestApplicationTests extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {
```

The main application class is this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBatchJsontestApplication {
```

None of them change anything else. There is no `context.xml` file, this is a SpringBoot application so everything is annotations only.

---

This is the end result that works very well for me

```
  @Profile("test")
  @Bean(name = TaskManagementConfigUtils.SCHEDULED_ANNOTATION_PROCESSOR_BEAN_NAME)
  @Role(BeanDefinition.ROLE_INFRASTRUCTURE)
  public ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor scheduleBeanProcessorOverride() {
    logger.info("Test Profile is active, overriding ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor to prevent annotations from running during tests.");
    return new ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor() {
      @Override
      protected void processScheduled(Scheduled scheduled, Method method, Object bean) {
        logger.info(String.format("Preventing scheduling for %s, %s, %s", scheduled, method, bean.getClass().getCanonicalName()));
      }
    };
  }
```

Here is the POM configuration to trigger the testing profile, so I no longer have to do so explicitly in my `application.properties`.

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19</version>
    <configuration>
      <systemPropertyVariables>
        <spring.profiles.active>test</spring.profiles.active>
      </systemPropertyVariables>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: can you show more of your code? the surrounding `@Configuration` code and the unit test?

Comment: Please show your context xml or other code with configuration annonation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`@Profile`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.html) annotation doesn't do anything for a regular method, nor a method annotated with `@Scheduled`. The javadoc states

> The @Profile annotation may be used in any of the following ways:
>
> - as a type-level annotation on any class directly or indirectly annotated with `@Component`, including `@Configuration` classes
> - as a meta-annotation, for the purpose of composing custom stereotype annotations
> - **as a method-level annotation on any `@Bean` method**

The last case, in bold, is the only use of `@Profile` on a method.

If you want to enable the `@Scheduled` behavior under a specific profile, annotate the bean (definition) that contains it.

Comment: That makes sense. I guess I'll have to manually short-circuit the method by returning manually in this instance... or jerry-rig something with aspectj. Thank you for your clairification!

Comment: Move the scheduling to a single class, annotate that class with `@Profile` and `@Component` or the likes and you will get the behavior you want.

Comment: Along with a `@Profile`, as M. Deinum suggested,  I utilized this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21920710/1478636